# Vagrant: Ruby script to return name of last created file

Tags: ruby, vagrant

We have vagrant file with trigger like

```
DB_NAME="mydb"
TIME=(Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
SQL_BACKUPS=(Dir["./config/schema/*_#{DB_NAME}.sql"])

config.trigger.before [:destroy, :provision] do |trigger|
    trigger.info = "Dumping database to /vagrant/config/schema/#{TIME}_#{DB_NAME}.sql"
    trigger.run_remote = {inline: "mysqldump --add-drop-table -u #{DB_USERNAME} -p#{DB_PASSWORD} #{DB_NAME} > /vagrant/config/schema/#{TIME}_#{DB_NAME}.sql"}
end
```

in `/vagrant/config/schema/` we have backup files like:
`20181116160919_mydb.sql`

How to find in ruby all files like `*_mydb.sql` and / or return name of latest one created?

We want automatize db backup on destroy, provision & up.

EDIT:

```
SQL_BACKUPS=(Dir["./config/schema/*_#{DB_NAME}.sql"]).sort
SQL_BACKUPS.reverse.each do |filename|
    puts "#{filename}"
end
```

return lists with sql files

ps, I don't have Experience with Ruby.

Comment: What are the current results you are seeing?

Comment: I hope you're absolutely certain that the things you're interpolating in those strings can never, ever contain spaces or characters that might cause your shell to freak out.

Comment: @MattSchuchard return array with sql files.

Comment: @tadman The  sql file names are predefined.

Comment: are you looking for `.sort.last`?

Comment: @Stefan , yes good point this one works ```SQL_BACKUPS=(Dir["./config/schema/*_#{DB_NAME}.sql"]).sort.reverse.last```

Comment: FYI: we have both, `last` and `first` in Ruby ;-)

Comment: @Stefan  like ```end()``` in php. thx

Answer (score 0):

I know you have timestamped files but, if one doesn't have a timestamp or a way to distinguish the creation times, the method below is what I used for non-timestamped files.

`File::Stat` has a method `ctime`(returns the creation time), So it can be done like.

```
SQL_BACKUPS=Dir["./config/schema/*_#{DB_NAME}.sql"].map { |f| {name: f, ctime: File::Stat.new(f).ctime } }
sorted = SQL_BACKUPS.sort_by { |f| f[:ctime] }
sorted.last.name # gives the one that was created the last.
```

Comment: Perhaps `SQL_BACKUPS.max_by { |f| f[:ctime] }.name` if "or" in "and / or" in the question.

Comment: @cary That even better.
But in my case I needed the complete ordered list.